# What is the game console that Sasahara used?

Tags: nichijou

What is the name of the console that Sasahara used to play with it when Tachibana Misato bombed him?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks like [Virtual Boy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Boy).

[image: Virtual Boy]

<sup>Image courtesy of [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Virtual-Boy-Set.jpg)</sup>

Taken from Wikipedia,

> The Virtual Boy is a 32-bit table-top video game console developed and manufactured by Nintendo. Released in 1995, it was marketed as the first console capable of displaying stereoscopic 3D graphics. Virtual Boy is also the first video game system ever to display in widescreen; [...]. The player uses the console in a manner similar to a head-mounted display, placing their head against the eyepiece to see a red monochrome display. The games use a parallax effect to create the illusion of depth.

Comment: oh, so it's an old console game

Comment: @Gagantous yeah... and a failure one: "*The Virtual Boy was panned by critics and was a commercial failure. Its failure has been cited as due to its high price, monochrome display, unimpressive 3D effect, lack of true portability, health concerns, and low quality games.*".

Comment: perhaps, it would be great if you added the additional info about that console on your answer

Comment: @Gagantous sorry, I don't think it helps anything with the question at all. Anyone can read the history & reception of it on the Wikipedia after all.

Comment: oh you are right